# Understanding dimensions in MultiHeadAttention layer of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm learning multi-head attention with [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-explained-visually-part-3-multi-head-attention-deep-dive-1c1ff1024853).
As the writer claimed, the structure of MHA (by the original paper) is as follows:

[image]

But the [`MultiHeadAttention`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention) layer of Tensorflow seems to be more flexible:

1. It does not require `key_dim * num_heads = embed_dim`. Like:

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads = 2, key_dim = 4)
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=[3, 5])
layer(x, x)
# no error
```

Does the depth of the weight matrix in `tf.MHA` layer set to `key_dim * num_heads` regardless of `embed_dim`? So that Q/K/V can still be properly split by `num_heads`.

2. However, the output depth of tf.MHA layer is (by default) guaranteed to be `embed_dim`. So there is a final dense layer with `embed_dim` nodes to ensure the dimension？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for 1 & 2. You can probe the weights by:

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads = 2, key_dim = 4, use_bias=False) #Set use_bias=False for simplicity.
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=[3, 5])
layer(x, x)
```

Get the weights associated,

```
weight_names = ['query', 'keys',  'values', 'proj']
for name, out in zip(weight_names,layer.get_weights()):
    print(name, out.shape)
```

Output shapes:

```
query (5, 2, 4) # (embed_dim, num_heads, key_dim)
keys (5, 2, 4)  # (embed_dim, num_heads, key_dim)
values (5, 2, 4) # (embed_dim, num_heads, value_dim/key_dim)
proj (2, 4, 5)  # (num_heads, key_dim, embed_dim)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Multi-Head Attention, we split our input size according to the embedding dimensions. How's that? Let's take an example...

```
#Take an arbitrarily input of with embed_size = 512
x_embed = tf.random.normal((64,100,512))
```

Now, here if you want 8 heads in Multi-Head Attention. Then `512//8` your embed size `512` should be evenly divisible by a number of heads... why's that? because this will decide the dimensions of your every attention.

```
Number of heads = 8
embed size = 512
Attention Dims = embed_size//Number of heads
```

If your no of heads were not evenly divisible by embed_size then it will cause trouble making in reshaping! but how? let's look into that...

```
batch_dims = 64
no_of_heads = 8
seq_dims = 100
attn_dims = 64

tf.reshape(x (batch_dims, no_of_heads, seq_dims, attn_dims))

#After reshaping x shape would be

shape(64 , 8 , 100 , 64)
```

**Important Note**

`tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention()` works the same your *query* may be different in `seq_length` from *key* and *value* but their embedding dimensions must be the same for all..